# Access Webservice return value

Tags: web-services, arraylist, http-request

I have a webservice which returns an arraylist of objects.
I want to access this arraylist of objects in my android code. How do i do it?
My webservice is

```
package com.chillum.first;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

@Path("/hello")
public class ServerSide {

@GET
public ArrayList<myClass> Print (@QueryParam("param1") String key) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyyhmmss");
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
    String command = "cmd /c start /wait C:\\python27\\tutorial\\check.bat "+key+" "+formattedDate;
    Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    p.waitFor();
    myClass[] flipkart=new myClass[500];
    myClass[] amazon=new myClass[500];
    myClass[] myntra=new myClass[500];
    myClass[] jabong=new myClass[500];
    myClass[] shopclues=new myClass[500];
    myClass[] hs18=new myClass[500];
    myClass[] indiatimes=new myClass[500];
    myClass[] croma=new myClass[500];

    String xmlFileNames[]=new String[8];
    xmlFileNames[0]="C:/python27/tutorial/"+formattedDate+"flipkart.xml";
    xmlFileNames[1]="C:/python27/tutorial/"+formattedDate+"amazon.xml";
    xmlFileNames[2]="C:/python27/tutorial/"+formattedDate+"myntra.xml";
    xmlFileNames[3]="C:/python27/tutorial/"+formattedDate+"jabong.xml";
    xmlFileNames[4]="C:/python27/tutorial/"+formattedDate+"shopclues.xml";
    xmlFileNames[5]="C:/python27/tutorial/"+formattedDate+"hs18.xml";
    xmlFileNames[6]="C:/python27/tutorial/"+formattedDate+"indiatimes.xml";
    xmlFileNames[7]="C:/python27/tutorial/"+formattedDate+"croma.xml";

    String[] domain=new String[8];
    domain[0]="http://www.flipkart.com";
    domain[1]="";
    domain[2]="http://www.myntra.com";
    domain[3]="";
    domain[4]="http://www.shopclues.com";
    domain[5]="http://www.homeshop18.com";
    domain[6]="http://www.shopping.indiatimes.com";
    domain[7]="http://www.cromaretail.com/";


    try {
        random(flipkart, xmlFileNames[0], domain[0]);
        random(amazon, xmlFileNames[1], domain[1]);
        random(myntra, xmlFileNames[2], domain[2]);
        random(jabong, xmlFileNames[3], domain[3]);
        random(shopclues, xmlFileNames[4], domain[4]);
        random(hs18, xmlFileNames[5], domain[5]);
        random(indiatimes, xmlFileNames[6], domain[6]);
        random(croma, xmlFileNames[7], domain[7]);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList<myClass> all= new ArrayList<myClass>();
    for(int i=0, j=0; i<50; i++, j++)
    {
        try
        {
            all.add(flipkart[i]);
            all.add(amazon[i]);
            all.add(myntra[i]);
            all.add(jabong[i]);
            all.add(shopclues[i]);
            all.add(hs18[i]);
            all.add(indiatimes[i]);
            all.add(croma[i]);
        }
        catch(NullPointerException npe)
        {
        }
            continue;
    }
    return all;
}
public static void random(myClass[] obj, String fileName, String domain) throws Exception
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    try
    {
        Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new FileReader( new File(fileName))));
        NodeList title = document.getElementsByTagName("title");
        NodeList price = document.getElementsByTagName("price");
        NodeList link = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
        NodeList image = document.getElementsByTagName("image");
        for (int i = 0; i < title.getLength(); i++) {
            int objcount=0;
            NodeList titleChildList = title.item(i).getChildNodes();
            NodeList priceChildList = price.item(i).getChildNodes();
            NodeList linkChildList = link.item(i).getChildNodes();
            NodeList imageChildList = image.item(i).getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < titleChildList.getLength(); j++) {
                obj[objcount]=new myClass();
                Node titleChildNode = titleChildList.item(j);
                if ("value".equals(titleChildNode.getNodeName())) {

                    obj[objcount].title=titleChildList.item(j).getTextContent()
                            .trim();
                }
                Node priceChildNode = priceChildList.item(j);
                if ("value".equals(priceChildNode.getNodeName())) {
                    obj[objcount].price=priceChildList.item(j).getTextContent()
                            .trim();
                }   
                Node linkChildNode = linkChildList.item(j);
                if ("value".equals(linkChildNode.getNodeName())) {
                    obj[objcount].link=domain+linkChildList.item(j).getTextContent()
                        .trim();
                }
                Node imageChildNode = imageChildList.item(j);
                if ("value".equals(imageChildNode.getNodeName())) {
                    obj[objcount].image=imageChildList.item(j).getTextContent()
                        .trim();
                }
                objcount++;
            }
        }   
    }
    catch(NullPointerException npe) {
    }

}

}
```

And my java class which returns to android is

```
package com.example.chillum;

import android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient;

import com.example.chillum.Utils;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HttpManager {

public static ArrayList<myClass> getdata(String uri)
{
    AndroidHttpClient client=AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("AndroidAgent");
    HttpGet request=new HttpGet(uri);
    HttpResponse response;
    try{
        response=client.execute(request);
        return //what?;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        client.close();
    }
}
}
```

What should i return such that i get the array list?
This methods returns to an async task where the other operations are to be done with the arraylist. 
please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't transfer a Java Object from the server to the client using HTTP.
HTTP uses basic ASCII text to transfer data (hence Hyper **Text** Transfer Protocol).

The workaround that needs to be used is using a standard markup language to encode the data you are sending from the server. The major ones that are used right now are JSON and XML.

JSON looks like this :

```
{ 
"company": Volkswagen,
"name": "Vento",
"price": 800000
}
```

And XML Looks like this :

```
<car>
<company>Volkswagen</company>
<name>Vento</name>
<price>800000</price>
</car>
```

In simple terms: You will have to convert the Object you want to send to JSON/XML before emitting to the client request. Then use a JSON decode function at the client side to get back the object.

There are quite a good number of tutorials to show how to use JSON/XML to transfer data between server and Android Activity.

Hope this helps.